# Can not install any media package/software

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, dependencies, media

I've had vlc, audacious working very well on my ubuntu 14.04. All of a sudden today I noticed that they're both gone. Also my default Ubuntu video player has stopped playing because of missing dependencies. But when it prompts me to install the dependencies, I get this message:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I tried to `sudo apt-get install vlc`

I also get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried all these commands but couldn't work :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I don't know what exactly I did that caused this issues.
Please I need help I cant play any video.